# Creating and removing Ember Models dynamically / at runtime

Tags: dynamic, ember.js, ember-data

I have been working on this for a couple of days now and have decided to bite the bullet and ask for help.

I am using ember-cli, and I'm trying to create Ember Models dynamically at runtime based on some metadata.  An sample use case would be if a user wanted to specify a data set (query, file etc.); I would like to read the user's data file and setup a model based on the file's structure.

I have successfully setup an ember-cli application which uses Ember Data and Fixtures (for simplicity).  My static example has three models and I can see the models and the data in the Store when I use the Chrome Ember debugger.

Now on to my dynamic example...

I have been able to successfully define a model at runtime by setting it up in IndexRoute

```
var IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    init: function() {
        // Create a simple model dynamically
        var MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
            defineAttributes: function(){
                Ember.defineProperty(this, 'col1', DS.attr()); 
                Ember.defineProperty(this, 'col2', DS.attr()); 
                Ember.defineProperty(this, 'col3', DS.attr());      
            }.on('init')
        });

        // insert some data into our model
        MyModel.reopenClass({
          FIXTURES: [
            {
                id: '1',
                col1: "key1",
                col2: "value1",
                col3: "value2"
            }, 
            {
                id: '2',
                col1: "key2",
                col2: "value1",
                col3: "value2"
            },             
            {
                id: '3',
                col1: "key3",
                col2: "value1",
                col3: "value2"
            }       
          ]
       });  
    }
});
```

The problem is that I don't see where the model has been placed, and it doesn't appear in the Chrome debugger in the Data (store).

If I change the definition of `MyModel` to `Ember.Application.MyModel` then I can see the Model is defined under `Ember.Application` in the console but it still isn't visible to the Ember Debugger.

I then tried to extend the above example to add the `model` hook as follows:

```
var IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    init: function() {
        ...
    },
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('my-model');
    }
});
```

But the call to `this.store.findAll('my-model')` fails in both cases.  I am assuming that I am not wiring things up correctly.

In my example I am also aware that the name of my Model is not dynamic either so I really want to know how to create a name for my model programmatically at runtime.

I would really appreciate some help or guidance from those out there who are more experienced with the framework because I've been really impressed with Ember and the whole configuration over convention approach.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: By the time you're finished with this you're going to have learned far more about Ember than you ever really wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially defining something, then throwing it away.  You'll need to attach it to your app's namespace (you can see it in your index file or configuration file if you're using Ember-cli).

Additionally, I doubt defining attributes on `init` will work, it might, but it isn't actually necessary.

Thirdly, do you really want to use Ember Data for this?  Ember Data is very opinionated, and it sounds like you don't want to define things.